# Error executing Oracle Anonymous Block in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I have the following anonymous block which runs just fine in Oracle SQL Developer and performs the expected insert but when I run it from my ASP.NET Code it bombs out (exception details below).

```
DECLARE
  L_PKID      NUMBER;
  P_NOTE_TXT  ICE.NOTE_TEXT.NOTE_TEXT%TYPE;
  P_USERID    ICE.NOTE_TEXT.CREATED_BY%TYPE;
  L_USER_NAME ICE.NOTE.CREATED_BY_NAME%TYPE;

BEGIN
  P_NOTE_TXT  := 'This is a sample note. There are many like it but this one is mine.';
  P_USERID   := 'SIMMONSJ404';
  --
  -- Get primary key, user name:
  --
  SELECT oid_seq.nextval INTO L_PKID FROM dual;

  SELECT FIRST_NAME||' '||LAST_NAME INTO L_USER_NAME
  FROM ICE.USR
  WHERE USR_ID = P_USERID
  AND ROWNUM = 1
  ORDER BY DATE_CREATED DESC;

  --
  -- BEGIN INSERTS: Note, Note_Text:
  --
  INSERT INTO ICE.NOTE (
  NOTE_OID, SYS_GENR_NOTE_IND, CREATED_BY_NAME, MODIFIED_BY_NAME,
  LAST_MOD_DTE, USR_CRTE_DTE, CREATED_BY, DATE_CREATED, RECORD_STATUS,
  DATE_MODIFIED, MODIFIED_BY, WRITE_COUNT, BUS_AREA_NOTE_CAT_ID
  ) VALUES (
  L_PKID, '0', L_USER_NAME, L_USER_NAME,
  sysdate, sysdate, P_USERID, sysdate, 'A',
  sysdate, P_USERID, 1, 3000000);

  INSERT INTO ICE.NOTE_TEXT (
  NOTE_OID, NOTE_LINE_NBR, NOTE_TEXT, RECORD_STATUS,
  DATE_CREATED, DATE_MODIFIED, WRITE_COUNT
  ) VALUES ( 
  L_PKID, 1, P_NOTE_TXT, 'A',
  sysdate, sysdate, 1);


END;       
COMMIT;
```

The error I get from .NET is:

```
System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException (0x80131938): ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> form
   current cursor
```

The pl/sql above is simply declared in a `var sql = @"";` block for now with hard-coded values which will be swapped out when I demonstrate I can get the insert to work from C#. Execution is done by building up an `OracleCommand` object with a connection and the sql then calling `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

What am I missing?

Comment: You have not included the C# code for executing this in your question. That's essential. Please include it.

Comment: The code is executed with OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: That is not sufficient. You need to provide more code than that, and it needs to be *in your question*. We should not have to ask for this, you should anticipate it. Please familiarize yourself with [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ralph W. gave me the answer:

The C# app on Windows terminates lines with Environment.NewLine and Oracle doesn't like this. Doing the following corrects this: `sql.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"\n")`

This solved the error cited above but then reveals that `COMMIT;` causes an error because `ExecuteNonQuery()` implicitly adds a COMMIT. Removed that from the query and now all is working.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed something, and I'm not sure but...maybe you need to escape the ' (single quote) in the comment : `-- Get primary key, user''s name:`

Comment: Doesn't make a difference -- deleted the comments just to make sure and it doesn't change the error message.

Comment: This problem is sometime created when there is an encoding problem. Make sure that the text is clean, no special non-visible characters, unicode, non-breaking spaces e.t.c.

Comment: You mean running the SQL through a something like a UTF encoder? I presume the Oracle server is on Unix or Linux; the web app is Windows.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the server is. I assume that you've created the pl/sql in a editor (like Toad for example) and than copy-paste it in Visual Studio. That happened to me some years ago and I remember that the issue was that the end of line was not properly interpreted.

Comment: Also, you're creating an anonymous block for executing 5 instruction (commit included) and I assume you have only one ExecuteNonQuery instruction for the entire block. I would encourage you to split the code in 4 ExecuteNonQuery instructions and call them in a transaction (TransactionScope). I'm not sure that .net can properly interpret the block declaration